# replacing "\N" with regex

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Can someone help me fix this notepad++ regex so that it will replace the text `\N` with a space?

```
((?=.*?,Default)[^\r\n]*)(\N)
```

I'm looking to replace all instances of the text `\N` only on lines that have `,Default` on it.

Comment: Nothing happens when you find `\r\n` and replace it with blank space?

Comment: what do you mean?

when i search for "\r\n" it finds the end of a line.

Comment: Does `\N` have to be after `,Default` or do they only have to be present in the same line? See [`,Default.*\K\\N`](https://regex101.com/r/ZXTI8s/1) for the first and [`^(?=.*,Default).*\K\\N`](https://regex101.com/r/bpX6QQ/1) for the second case.

Comment: Do you want to replace newline character or specifically \N? If it's the second you have to escape \ with backslash, so it would be \\N.

Comment: @Sebastian Proske

they just have to be on the same line

Aleksandar Makragić

I need to specifically replace \N

Comment: @Sebastian Proske

Yours selects the text properly but i can't replace it with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*,Default)).*?\K\\N
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z9YQQy/1).

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*,Default))` - a start of the line location that contains `,Default` substring (`^(?=.*,Default)`) or the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`, as `\G` matches the start of string/line, its position must be subtracted with a negative lookahead)
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\K` - a match reset operator
- `\\N` - a literal `\N` substring.

A test in Notepad++:

```
\NSome text,Default\Nand more here\N
\Ntext \N text ,Default
New line \N\N\N
```

becomes
[image]

Comment: The replacement may be any you like, I used a space.

Comment: follow up question

can the search be modified to include space before or after the \N ?

such as " \N" or "\N "

Comment: @Tyler: If the space should only be horizontal, and there may be 0 or more, use `\h*`: `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*,Default)).*?\K\h*\\N\h*`.